Dropping a unique clustered index on identity colum
I'm currently working with a SQL Server database that came from an inherited system. The previous system used a lot of auto incrementing bigint identity fields, let's call the field "KeyID". These KeyID columns are interspersed throughout the database but in our implementation of the app, KeyID is being ignored. There are values for the fields in the tables, but KeyID is not used in any way.
I've noticed that for each table that has a KeyID field, a unique clustered index has been been created for it, IX_Tablename.
I am considering dropping these indices to optimize the number of indices the server needs to maintain, but am not sure what the long term effects will be. The resources I find online seem to assume, I believe, that the identity column is the primary key, and say that deleting the clustered index for that column will result in the table becoming a heap. But KeyID is not a primary key, the PK's are separate Guid columns with their own unique non-clustered indices. The tables with the KeyID index are clustered on a value that is not referenced and so no seeks are performed on their values.
Is their any advantage to keeping them or should I remove these indices?
I am not ready to delete the columns themselves, so they will still need to be there and auto-increment, will their missing indices affect the creation of the next auto-incremented value?

leave it alone
In most OLTP workloads, the primary key is a surrogate key. This isn't a bad thing, especially because someone came along and decided that GUIDs are the best way to uniquely identify various entities in your application. Sure, I get it, it's hard to run out of GUIDs, but that's about where their helpfulness ends.
Even if you were using integer or big integers to uniquely identify entities, there's a strong chance that an identity column would be in use to assign them. As an example, every table in the Stack Overflow database has a clustered primary key on an identity column, and those values are used to identify:

Users who posted questions
Users who voted
Posts that were voted on
Posts that were commented on
Comments that will be deleted because comments were a mistake

There's absolutely nothing wrong with surrogate keys, as long as you have sufficient (unique) indexes on the GUID columns that queries will be performing their lookups via.
Having a clustered primary key on an integer or big integer column buys you a few things that using GUIDs does not:

Narrow data type (4-8 bytes)
Uniqueness
Monotonically increasing
Non-updated data (insert/delete only)

One of the more important parts -- monotonically increasing -- is often not an attribute when GUIDs are used, because they're usually randomly generated. Very few application developers have the foresight to use NEWSEQUENTIALID() to assign GUIDs in the database, and instead generate them in the application, or just by using NEWID() in the database.
For OLTP workloads, having a clustered index (particularly one that meets the criteria I listed above) is far superior to not having one. Tables without clustered indexes (Heaps) in SQL Server can behave in unexpected ways when updated, or deleted from. If you're interested in this, look up forwarded records, and empty allocated pages in this context.
If you were to use non-sequential GUIDs for a clustered index, you would be making random inserts and doing a lot of data page reshuffling, and logging of that reshuffling. It may not matter when a database is small, but it could certainly start to get annoying for larger tables and indexes.
A common scenario for SQL Server is to have a surrogate unique clustered index on an integer or big integer column, and a non-clustered primary key on the GUID column(s) that make up a unique row. That's what you have currently, so don't worry about changing your tables to suit a different arrangement. Instead, just create unique indexes on your GUID columns where queries will use them. One reason for that arrangement is that clustered index key column(s) are automatically added to non-clustered indexes -- as a key when not unique, and as an include when unique -- so the narrow clustered index is more ideal.
In short, leave it alone. You are barking up the wrong tree for optimizing anything whatsoever about your workload.

Clustered indexes and heaps are the base table, where all data is stored.  Clustered indexes have the data stored ordered by the cluster key while heaps are generally ordered by their insert order.  Nonclustered indexes are a separate beast.  But adding or changing a clustered index will require a full rebuild (basically pick up the entire table and put it down again  in the new order).
The clustered index (which does not have to be the primary key) determines the order in which rows are stored.  If the GUID is randomly generated (i.e. NOT sequential) then it will prove to be a bad cluster key (and not just because of it's datasize).  Ideally the cluster key is eternally incrementing.
Personally, given what I know of the table so far, I would have done the same thing, used an integer (or bigint) as the cluster key as a decent compromise and then index the heck out of the GUID or business keys using non-clustered indexes.
Another caveat about heaps is that when records are deleted that the space is not made available to the engine until the heap is rebuilt. This may or may not be of significant concern to you, but is something to keep in mind.
My Advice?
Given that your primary key is a GUID and it's unlikely to be sequential is to leave this as is.  The clustered index doesn't take up any more space than a heap and will under most circumstances give you cleaner execution plans than a heap OR the alternative of making the GUID the clustered key.
Storage is cheap and unless you are far outside the curve on I/O and data access patterns you are unlikely to see performance issues around simply having lots of indexes; and I wouldn't start cleanup here, take a look at the other indexes and see if they can be consolidated if you are concerned about that.

Erik Darling and Jonathan Fite both give valuable things to consider in their answers.
I want to add an additional caution to what Jonathan mentions, about dropping a clustered index leading to effectively re-writing the entire table.
When a clustered index exists on a table in SQL Server, the clustered index key is used in every nonclustered index to identify rows.
So, dropping a clustered index involves re-writing the table as a heap. And re-writing the nonclustered btree indexes as well, to replace the clustered index key which is being removed with a row identifier which can be used against the heap.
So… changes for a clustered index in a large table should be some of the last index changes considered. After changes to any nonclustered index, or addition of a new (filtered) btree index, or new (filtered) columnstore index.
Sometimes changing/dropping clustered index is the right move. But it should be clearly and strongly motivated.

When you drop a clustered index, the clustered index leaf pages become a heap without having to be re-written.  Non-clustered indexes are re-written to switch from using clustered index keys as row locators to the file:page:slot rowid's used by heaps.
